# PHPMailer and Spanish Characters

Tags: special-characters

I am having trouble with Spanish special characters in emails not displaying correctly. I am using PHPMailer version 6.6.0.

I have tried the following in my project but I get errors:
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "CharSet" on null in...

and

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mailer->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "Encoding" on null in...

I have tried also
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
But still do not display correctly.

Example of what is displayed in Outlook: Comentario: S?bado Ma?ana

If I send “Sábado” and “Mañana” from Thunderbird they display correctly in Thunderbird and Outlook.

A search of what has worked for others is not working for me. Is it possible to have special characters in other languages display correctly in emails? If yes, what do I need to do to get it working in my project?

I have tried also
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
But still do not display correctly.

Comment: I have found that I have to use HTML codes in the email body to get the special Spanish characters to display.
Example: To display ñ I use &ntilde; 
and to dipslay á I use &aacute;
This site gives a table of HTML codes to use for each special character: https://www.thoughtco.com/html-codes-spanish-characters-4062194

Answer (score 0):

**Run PHPMailer with Composer**

Install composer and verify installation on your server by the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt install composer
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
composer install
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace

These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

Load Composer's autoloader

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```